# How do I make alternating row colors in a Mustache.js template?

Tags: templates, mustache

I have a template:

```
{{#people}}
  <div style="background-color: **gray/white**;"><span>{{name}}</span>: <span>{{title}}</span></div>
{{/people}}
```

Is there a way to set that background-color without passing it in from my controller?  This is purely display and I do not feel that it belongs in my controller as a result, so would like to avoid naming colors there if possible.

Comment: Just as you wrote, "purely display". So I would use CSS3: `div:nth-child(2n+1) { background-color: gray } div:nth-child(2n) { background-color: white }` Regarding Mustache, as far as I know it can not solve this.

Comment: @manatwork: make your comment an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: do you know that `nth-child()` and similar selectors are supported in Explorer only since version 9? There is accent on *I would use*, which is by far not *I recommend it to others*.

Comment: @manatwork: I understand... but this is not a huge feature, just something I will reward users of modern browsers with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, Mustache can not solve this, however I found a mustache.js-specific way:

```js
var template = '{{#people}}'
  +'  <div style="background-color: {{color}}"><span>{{name}}</span>: <span>{{title}}</span></div>'
  +'{{/people}}'

var data = {
  people: [
    {name: 'a', title: 'b'},
    {name: 'c', title: 'd'},
    {name: 'e', title: 'f'},
    {name: 'g', title: 'h'},
    {name: 'i', title: 'j'},
  ],
  color: function() {
    return window.divcolor = window.divcolor == 'gray' ? 'white' : 'gray'
  }
}

Mustache.to_html(template, data)
```

Comment: In case you are using node.js and want to render, for example, an email body, the window object is naturally not available. In that case you need to simply define the divcolor variable outside the data object.